# Escaping special characters in velocity template

Tags: java, html, velocity

I have this template in vm:

```
<div>
    $submitterMessage
</div>
```

The variable $submitterMessage contains the special character like è,à,ò.

In my template the output of variable is:
� � � �

How I can resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In that context you should apply HTML encoding/escaping.
According to velocity a ready function is:
http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html#html%28%29

For a more complex context like: html attributes, nested javascript etc... you could use also ESAPI by OWASP or http://www.unbescape.org/.
This will prevent also XSS vulnerabilities in your code.

Last but not least, you would probably want to work with a UTF-8 output;
Set the right content type header in the http response and in the html headers in the page.

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example or URL to show how to use OWASP with Velocity?

Comment: Since the posted link is not working anymore I add here the new link to the Velocity Escape Tool page https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/EscapeTool.html#html()

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the HTML5 charset as Tom Kriek suggested can be done directly in your template, in the `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

But then, you also have to tell Velocity that you're outputting UTF-8 characters. You just have to add the following to your `velocity.properties` file:

```
input.encoding = UTF8
output.encoding = UTF8
```

You'll only have to resort to the EscapeTool for outputting '<', '&,', '>', ...

Comment: Deleting my answer. Completely missed that this wasn't php! For reference sake this was my PHP answer if anybody would need it. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`